# 'she will always complain' versus 'she is always complaining' - any difference?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-continuous

Is there any difference between

> she will always complain

and

> she is always complaining

Does the first mean that it is bad habit that she always does in any time and does the second mean in some very precise occasions.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I think the question was initially about the difference between *She always complains* and *She is always complaining*.

Comment: @V.V. AlanCarmack has not changed the text of the question  at all. You can see the editing history by clicking on **edited X hours ago**.

Comment: I am sorry,  I must have misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that there is an implied difference between "**will complain**" (future tense) and "**is complaining**" (present tense).

The first implies a specific (perhaps avoidable) future event whereas the second one is her current state.

> Don't leave the toilet seat up. She **will complain** about it. She's not
>   complaining now and is not someone who necessarily complains a lot,
>   but she will complain about that.

vs

> It doesn't matter if you leave the toilet seat up or not. She **is
>   always complaining**. She is complaining about something right now and
>   will continue to do so for the foreseeable future. Leaving the toilet seat
>   up or down will not impact her complaining.

Comment: The first can also be used with conditionals to imply action taken after the conditional: "She will always complain if you give her warm water" (also works with the clauses reversed). I would also argue that in standard English "is always" implies habitual behavior, rather than simply the current state. Compare AAVE, where un-conjugated "be" is a habitual marker: "she always be complaining".

Answer (score 0):

[will](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will) has many possible meanings, one of which is **used when referring to something that always or usually happens**

> she will always complain

In this sense, it means exactly the same as

> she is always complaining

Comment: It might be subtle difference, but "she will always complain" has a certain degree of speaker's expectation while "she is always complaining" just describes her disposition. I don't think they have the same meaning and they could always be used in the same context interchangeably. I would not use **exactly**.

Comment: The first is a habitual action, the second shows irritation.